# read and delete instantaneous data from a file using tcp socket using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, readfile

I am using python to send instantaneous data from a client(C1) to server(S) using TCP socket. This data is saved in the server(S) in a text file. Now this file gets appended with the new data frequently. I was able to achieve this successfully.

Now I need to create a new script to read from the same file and send the data to a different client(C2) at the same time. As soon as I read the data I need to remove the data read from the file. How can I do this?

Comment: Two processes having write access to the same file at the same time? Not sure if that's a good idea. If you are on a Unix platform, you might want to take a look at AF_UNIX sockets for IPC between your two server processes. [Here](https://gist.github.com/jmhobbs/11276249)'s an example for that.

Comment: @shmee: I was thinking like one process will wait till the other closes the file. This at a time only one file will have access to the file.

Comment: How would you let one process know that the other currently uses the file? All options, that immediately come to mind, are vulnerable to race conditions. Even if you get exclusive write access done, you might introduce delays and potential issues with buffering. You seem to be trying to make regular files work like queues. I wouldn't necessarily call that impossible, but getting it right is likely more complicated than using a "proper" IPC method in the first place.

Comment: I know that it is not recommended to write to a same file from 2 different process or threads. But I need to this in my case. Since it is tricky, I was asking for the solution here

Comment: There is no good solution and I refuse to create and publish a bad one for beginners, that might come across it, to adopt and use. Please explain the requirements of your runtime that allow two processes to communicate through a regular file, but make the use of literally any means of inter process communication impossible. This seems like an XY problem.